# Dealing with Graphical User Interfaces in Haskell

Tags: user-interface, haskell

I am an intermediate Haskell programmer and I would now deal with Graphical User Interfaces. Where to begin ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The [Haskell Wiki book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell) provides a page dedicated to some of the [choices](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GUI).  This is expanded on in more detail on the [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/GUI_libraries) itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there one among these libraries suitable for beginners?

Comment: If your on Linux then gtk2hs is probably familiar if you've done any GTK before?  Another choice is to use a web package like Yesod  and just write a web-based UI.